"Schaden anrichten" vs. "Schaden zufügen"
Ich habe die Meinung gehört, dass Schaden anrichten unabsichtlichen Schaden bezeichne, während Schaden zufügen absichtliches Leid impliziere. Allerdings zeigt die Korpusanalyse, dass sowohl anrichten als auch zufügen in beiden Kontexten verwendet werden. Auch Daten von Context Reverso unterstützen diese Unterscheidung nicht.
Fühlt ihr einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Ausdrücken?

Der eine Ausdruck erfordert ein Dativobjekt, der andere erlaubt nicht mal eines.

(einen) Schaden anrichten
jemandem (einen) Schaden zufügen

Wenn man also sagen will, wer den Schaden hat, muss man zufügen verwenden, ansonsten anrichten.

Ja, eine andere Person hat mir das gerade auch gesagt. Vielen Dank!

"Wenn man also sagen will, wer den Schaden hat, muss" - das sollte mE eher andersherum formuliert werden: Wenn man sagen will, wer den Schaden hat, kann man immerhin auch "Schaden bei <Geschädigtem> anrichten" sagen, wohingegen man "anrichten" verwenden muss, wenn man den Geschädigten nicht nennen will.

Der Bedeutungsunterscheid ist, daß "Schaden anrichten" nur den Unterschied mit und ohne Schaden feststellt, aber "Schaden zufügen" auch eine Person (oder zumindest juristische Körperschaft) erkennt, der der Schaden entstanden ist. Wer zum Beispiel mit dem Auto gegen einen Ampelmast fährt, hat einen Schaden angerichtet (denn man muß Arbeit/Kosten aufwenden um das zu reparieren), aber der Ampel
ist der Schaden nicht zugefügt worden (sie hat nicht Aua geschrien), allenfalls der Gemeinde, aber die wird hier als nicht-personifiziertes Neutrum angesehen.
